# How to make a div hidden behind a fixed div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a website where there is a navigation sidebar which position is fixed in the left and I have the content in the right side. Now when I shrink the browser window width a horizontal scroll bar is introduced. When I use that to scroll the content the content overflow's above the fixed left sidebar. I want the content to go behind the side bar so that its not collapsed. Please visit the site. Thank you.

[Link to site](http://s133036305.onlinehome.us/#home)

Comment: have u given background-position?

Comment: Please add some code when you ask questions. The better questions, the  better answers

Comment: Also, Lets say someone comes to this question a year from now. Will the link still be active? If not, try asking without the link.

Comment: Ya sure. Sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css, set the background colour for `#navigation` to white and give it a higher z-index...

```
#navigation {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: more than 7 years after, this answer was extremely useful!

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color and the z-index

```
.navigation {
    z-index:100;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Read more about the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: gr8...working fine..I have not experimented with z-index. Let me study that. Thank you very much..:)

Answer (score 0):

You Need Yo Use **z-index property**

*The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order*.

**Note:** *z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).*

More At [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
#navigation {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```